# res.send does not operate properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Just trying to send a resposne from `express` app to the front side to show an alert.
 So following is what I've tried in app to get it work:

```
if (info.messageId) {
         res.redirect('back');
        res.send({ success: true });    
    }
```

and here is what I have in front side:

```
 $.ajax({
            success: function (returns) {
                if (returns)
                    alert("True");
                else
                    alert("False");
            }
        });
```

but neither it shows true nor false.However `res.redirect('back')` works properly but not `res.send`. If you need more info or code, I will send.

also tried to find the solution in already asked Q and A's but did not find any clear one.
 Then any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

You can only respond to a request once.

You cannot simultaneously say "To get what you asked for, go to this other URL" and "Here is what you asked for".

`res.redirect` **or** `res.send`: Pick only one.

Comment: by choosing `res.send` it goes to a page just showing `{"success":true}`!!

Comment: @Yasin — Then I imagine that your client side JS isn't running and you are submitting a form to the URL which returns that JSON.